# How to write logs in a file using apache spark

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, log4j

I am working on a maven project. Apache spark has its own log4j functionality. Is there a way using which I can write apache spark logs and my own log statements to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As any other java application, you need jars in classpath and you need a log4j config file.

**[1] Jars in classpath**

Spark already comes with these 2 in its `jars` folder (under `$SPARK_HOME`):

```
slf4j-api-1.7.16.jar 
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar
```

So you just need a "provided" in your pom so you can compile with it:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.16</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Note that a different version of Spark may come with a different version of slf so take a look in the [jars] folder to match the correct version to the Spark you use.

**[2] A log4j config file**

- Go to the `conf` folder under spark home dir.
- Rename this file `log4j.properties.template` to `log4j.properties`
- Add your config

Now you can add `log.debug` in your code.

Note that code may run on the Driver or the Executor so the logs will be in different machines depending on where it runs.